# During Krishna's period did people know he was God?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

During krishna's period did people know he was God and avatar of lord Vishnu?

If they knew, why did people fight against him in Mahabharata war? As he was God if people knew it why would anyone go against him when he supported Pandava?

If people knew he was god? Why did not all people fall to his feet, accepting all he says?